# How do I cast void* to NSString without getting a Runtime Error, in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, casting, nsstring, void-pointers

There are many posts about handling casting a void*.  I have have followed their instructions.  However I am getting a runtime error when trying to cast a void* to NSString*.

I am pretty sure I am missing something simple. :-)

Consider the following code:

```
NSString* testString = @"This is a test";
NSLog(@"voidTest = %@", [self voidTest:&testString]);
```

And the following function:

```
- (NSString*)voidTest:(void*)testString
{
    NSString* value = (__bridge NSString *)(testString);
    return value;
}
```

When this code is run, the first line in the function gives me the the following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x1200000070)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not passing an `NSString*`, you're passing an `NSString**`.  Cast the string to `void *`, don't take its address.

Comment: That should be an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@dasblinkenlight, thanks for getting me going in the right direction.

So in the end the following code is what worked.

The function call:

```
NSString* testString = @"This is a test";
NSLog(@"voidTest = %@", [self voidTest:(__bridge void *)(testString)]);
```

The function:

```
- (NSString*)voidTest:(void*)testString
{
    NSString* value = (__bridge NSString *)(testString);
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is the extra dereference: you are passing a pointer to `NSString*`, which is itself a pointer.

You can fix this either by adding an extra dereference in `voidTest:`

```
NSString* value = *((__unsafe_unretained NSString **)(testString));
```

or by passing `testString` instead of `&testString` in the caller.

Neither of these solutions is ideal, because it forces a cast. Generally speaking, `void*` should be reserved for calls to C functions. When calling Objective-C to Objective-C, you could use the `id` type instead, which tells the compiler that you are passing an Objective-C object.

```
-(void)voidTest:(void*)ptr {
    NSString *val = *((__unsafe_unretained NSString **)(ptr));
    NSLog(@"%@", val);
}

-(void)testVoid {
    NSString *str = @"Hello";
    [self voidTest:&str];
}
```

Comment: ok so I tried NSString* value = *((__bridge NSString **)(testString));
I got an Incompatible types casting 'void*' to 'NSString *__strong*' with a __bridge cast and Pointer to non-const type 'NSString *'  with not explicit ownership. When I tried passing just testString, In the function call i got Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' to pointer type 'void *' requires a bridged cast
and in the function I got Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'void *' to pointer type 'NSString *' requires a bridged cast.

Comment: @user2517182 I changed `__bridge` to `__unsafe_unretained` and verified that the cast works, and that passing a pointer to `NSString*` produces the expected result. Please give it a try.

Comment: I changed __bridge to __unsafe_unretained, I get the following error: Cast of C pointer type 'void *' to Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *__unsafe_unretained' requires a bridged cast.

Comment: @user2517182 I posted code that compiled and worked fine in my environment.

Comment: I hear you.  I am sure it did.  There are so many moving parts with xcode so there is a good possibility that I did not set something correctly.  However, the code I posted below is what worked in my environment.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.